# Interpretation of Gauss's theorem applied to Maxwell's equations: $\dfrac{d}{dt} \int \rho \ dV + \int \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = 0$

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, conservation-laws, charge, maxwell-equations

Using Maxwell's equations and Gauss's theorem, we get

$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \int \rho \ dV + \int \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = 0,$$

where $\rho$ is the electric charge density and $\mathbf{j}$ is the electric current density.

Therefore, we have that

$$e = \int \rho \ dV$$

is the total charge.

Electric current is said to be $I = \dfrac{Q}{t}$, where $Q$ is quantity of charge in coulombs. So does this mean that the term $\dfrac{d}{dt} \int \rho \ dV$ is the current? After all, this is the change in total electric charge with respect to time, which matches $I$, right?

Or does this mean that $\int \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS$ is the electric current?

What do each of these two terms actually represent?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int \mathbf{j} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \, \mathrm{d} S$ is the integral of current density over a surface; this is equal to the total current passing through this surface. In your notation you could call this $I$.

$\int \rho \, \mathrm{d} V$ is the integral of charge density over a volume; this is equal to the total charge in the volume. You can denote this $Q$.

So the statement of Gauss's law can be written

$$I = -\frac{\mathrm{d} Q}{\mathrm{d} t};$$

the minus sign comes from the orientation of the surface: we define current flowing out of the surface to have a positive sign.

Comment: It is probably more natural to think of the former quantity as the current, though as the equality suggests they both have the same value.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The continuity equation states that the charge of a volume V can only change due to the electric flow (i.e. when they move outside or inside the volume). The same continuity equation holds for liquids as well, with $\varrho$ being the density and $j=\varrho v$, where $v$ is the velocity of the flow.

These continuity equations does not have source, but a general one do have it. For example, the continuity equation for the energy of the electromagnetic field is
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}+\text{div}S=-jE$$
Where $w$ is the energy density, i.e.
$$w=\frac{1}{2}(ED+BH)$$
And $S$ is the Poynting-vector:
$$S=E\times H$$
Integrating this equation to the whole space, we get that the total  energy can only change due to the external power $jE$.

Comment: So $\dfrac{d}{dt} \int \rho \ dV + \int \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = 0$ is called the "continuity equation"?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. You can read the wikiledia article about it too. Note that you can even have a "vectorial" continuity equarion. It happens, for example, in the case of the continuity equation of impulse: $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial x_j}=-\varrho E_i-(j \times B)_i$. Here, $T$ is a tensor, called Maxwell's energy-impulse tensor.